# Is it possible to use next auto_increment id and insert it with a prefix with PDO?

Tags: mysql, pdo

Is it possible to use the next Auto_increment ID and concat it with a prefix, on INSERT?

In my table i have a column named id, and it's primary and auto increment.
 Now i'd like to save that number with a text in another column.
It would be lie this:

```
id   nr1      nr2   concated
-----------------------------
0    123             123_missing-0
1    234             234_missing-1
2    423      2      423_2
3    342      1      342_1
4    564             564_missing-4
```

Where nr2 is missing i still need a unique value, and therefore i thought of using a prefix with id Concated.

I'm using PHP, PDO and mySQL.

```
INSERT INTO mytable SET column2 = CONCAT("hello_", id)
```

Comment: It's probably possible; but it's a really bad idea.

Comment: Why would you do that since you can retrieve that string formatted in a SELECT query ? [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) !

Comment: what does PDO have to do with this? Are you executing via MySQL or PHP?

Comment: Why i do this should not be a part of the question! I thought of doing this in PHP but maby i can do it in mySQL as a auto operation on Insert?

Comment: @treyBake The reason i mention PDO is because i found some info about this in mysq_li. But the query in PDO can work a bit difrent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather handle this use case while querying the database than inserting. Looks like it's being formatted for display purpose, if this is the case, you can write the `SELECT` query like this:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT("hello_", id)
FROM table;
```

Comment: Will hello be stuck on column id in this query? What if i like a new colum for the Concat? What i want is to save the prefix and the id in a new column. Maby can this be done inside mySql?

Comment: You can do it by writing an `AFTER INSERT` trigger but I would not do it as (a) it's a bad design and (b) it will impact the performance if all the `INSERT` queries. Could you let me know what the use case is?

Comment: I need to be able to find duplicates. Nr1 & Nr2 combined (Nr1_N2) creates a sort of id. There can be duplicates of this combines number, but i need to find them. Nr1 always exist, but Nr2 doesn't. So i needed to create a unique number for "Nr2" when it's empty. I know i can create a Query to Select and combine Nr1 & Nr2 but that would be to musch work to re-write a lot of querries. So first of all, i had to create something unique for missing Nr2...